# Parametrizing url in CherryPy

Tags: python, routes, cherrypy, mako

I have a `Root` object, and it maps to `/`.

It contains a chart, and clicking one of the lines in it, the user gets connected to another page `Pie`.

In `Pie`, there are two functions that take the same parameter.

```
def submit_data(self, wf_id, run_id, run_desc, day)
```

and

```
def submit_timeline_data(self, wf_id, run_id, run_desc, day)
```

I'd like to have the url mapped in such a way that when the user clicks a line, the values that correspond to the line is passed to the link address.

For example, if the line corresponds to values `wf_id = 1, run_id = 1, run_desc = "1", day = "2014-05-20"`, clicking the line connects the user to something like `/pie/1/1/1/2014-05-20`, or something similar, and these values are passed to the html template for `Pie`.

How can I do this?

Currently I am using `RoutesDispatcher()`, and setting all urls manually, but since `day` parameter can take any values, this is not possible any more.

I am using `Mako` template language.

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with -- constructing the URLs when Mako renders your template, or dispatching the URLs when they are used to call back to your CherryPy application?

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this...

```
@cherrypy.expose
def Pie(self, wf_id='', run_id='', run_desc='', day=''):
    if(wf_id == '' or run_id == '' or run_desc == '' or day=''):
        return """<a href='/pie/%s/%s/%s/%s'>click here</a>""" % (wf_id, run_id, run_desc, day)
    else:
    # update db
```

Hope this helps!